# Manejo de excepciones en Java

Tags: java, excepciones

Realizando un escaneo de código con Fortify me detecta la siguiente vulnerabilidad en mi código. La cual me dice lo siguiente:

> Si los bloques catch son varios, puede resultar incómodo y repetitivo,
>   pero si se "condensan" bloques catch obteniendo una clase de alto
>   nivel como Exception, se pueden ocultar excepciones que requieran un
>   tratamiento especial o que no se deberían obtener en este punto del
>   programa. Básicamente, filtrar una excepción demasiado amplia frustra
>   el propósito de las excepciones escritas de Java. Además, podría
>   volverse especialmente peligrosa si el programa crece y empieza a
>   lanzar nuevos tipos de excepciones.

El código es el siguiente:

```
try{ gzos.close(); } catch( Exception e ){}
try{ b64os.close(); } catch( Exception e ){}
try{ baos.close(); } catch( Exception e ){}
```

Los 3 bloques lanzan la excepcion del tipo `IOException`. Tengo dos posibles soluciones las cuales son las siguientes:

```
//Manera 1
try{ gzos.close(); } catch( IOException e ){}
try{ b64os.close(); } catch( IOException e ){}
try{ baos.close(); } catch( IOException e ){}

//Manera 2
try{ gzos.close();
     b64os.close();
     baos.close(); } catch( IOException e ){}
```

Ahora la pregunta es la siguiente ¿Como manejo la excepción de manera correcta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes que todo debo decir que es una muy mala práctica cerrar los recursos dentro del cuerpo/bloque del `try`, esto debe hacerse dentro del `finally`.

La mejor solución a tu caso en específico es utilizar un *try-with-resources*, introducido desde Java 7, del siguiente modo (dependiendo de tu versión de Java puedes hacer cosas diferentes).

```
// Java 7 y 8

// Instanciación de las variables dentro de los paréntesis
try ( InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) { 

    // Trabajo con los streams fis y baos
} catch (IOException e ) {
    // Código
}


// Instanciación de las varibles dentro de los paréntesis
try ( InputStream fis = otroFis;
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = otroBaos;) { 

    // Trabajo con los streams fis y baos
} catch (IOException e ) {
    // Código
}


// Java 9 y 10
try ( otroFis;
      otroBaos;) { 

    // Trabajo con los streams fis y baos
} catch (IOException e ) {
    // Código
}
```

NOTA: La diferencia principal entre las versiones del *try-with-resources* de Java 7 y el de Java 9, es que en el de Java 7, tenías que declarar dentro de los paréntesis las variables que ibas a utilizas en el cuerpo del `try` y en Java 9, puedes solo referenciar una variable definida fuera de dichos paréntesis.

Si te das cuenta, este mecanismo te evita tener que cerrar explícitamente los recursos, y además se encarga de manejar cualquier excepción que se produzca intentando cerrarlos. También te garantiza que todos los recursos serán cerrados, aunque durante el proceso de cerrar algún otro se produzcan excepciones.

Es importante tener en cuenta que para poder utilizar el *try-with-resources*, los objetos deben implementar la  interfaz `AutoClosable` (todas las clases del API de entrada salida de java la implementan, y si no me equivoco muchas de JDBC también).